# modx revolution slow backend

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Has anyone come up with a way to speed up the backend in modx?

I was thinking that creating a set of pages in modx with admin privileges to modify the site content, so that it looks customized, works in IE and is not slow.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of Revolution are you using?

In the latest release (2.07) a lot of work has been done on the manager and it has been claimed pages will load 50% faster than in previous releases.

Comment: I didn't check in the last few days, I'll have to give 2.07 a go (or wait for 2.07 pl2)

Comment: I'm doing some Revo development on a Samsung Netbook, using lightppd, the upgrade to 2.0.7-pl did have a noticable improvement in loading and response of the backend manager.

Answer (score 2):

> works in IE and is not slow

turn off firebug and your problem is solved.

Comment: It's slow in Chrome as-well. I think the backend is relying too much on Ajax calls, whose speed also depends on the server speed.

Comment: It's true about the many ajax requests.
1. debugging console is turned off in chrome?  (although i saw it less in chrome)

2. check if it's a server speed issue.   on one apache server i saw issues with KeepAlive that were very evident on the /manager page.  try "KeepAlive Off"

Answer (score 1):

Chrome works best for me...and modx 2.0.7 works faster.

edit:
Some people said that it works faster when you switch off on-line feeds(settings) in the main dashboard (bugs and news). Also the newest version 2.2 is pretty fast:)

Answer (score 0):

there is a cache package which will improve it prolly

http://modx.com/extras/package/xfpc

Answer (score 0):

use new php 5.5. it has a nice caching from php files.
I use it and it is great

Answer (score 0):

There is MODX [Ajax manager](http://modx.com/extras/package/ajaxmanager) which can make manager faster. Attention: some old extras can have issues with this one.