# Speeding up ModX Revolution ajax calls with database optimization

Tags: ajax, database, indexing, modx, modx-revolution

I'm dealing with some loading speed issues on a ModX Revolution (2.2.2-pl) installation. I believe the problem is rooted in the fact that hundreds of sites are hosted and accessible from the same administrator window, but unfortunately I don't have a say in that setup.

It seems that the ajax calls are puttering - fully loading the sidebar takes about 10 seconds, and saving takes about 15 seconds.

I was dabbling in some database stuff recently and came across some information on indexing. Space on the server is not a big concern, so is there something in the database I could index to speed up these calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into the javascript & css options, limits in the system settings?

The newest versions of modx are continue improving in speed [i.e. keep it updated to the latest]

Browsers will make a difference as well, I find Chrome is the fastest ~ I'm assuming it has the fastest javascript engine.

Other than that you should be able to customize the manager in such a way that you have a different administrative login for each context [each website] by creating admin users that only have access to each given context. You should be able to get lots of help for that one in the modx forums.

*EDIT***

There are several options in the manager that you can tweak/enable/disable that may help:
- Use Compressed CSS
- Use Compressed JavaScript Libraries
- Use Grouping When Compressing Javascript
- Maximum JavaScript Files Compressed
- Manager JS/CSS Compression Cache Age

Though most of these will already be 'optimized'

I think there is a way to disable the resource browser refreshing when you save as well, but I can't seem to find it now.

If your administration has already been restricted to different contexts I don't think you should even be able to see a resource that is not in the context you have access to. i.e. if you can still see other resources, then you still have ~some~ sort of access. It sounds to me like your problem is the time it takes for the resource browser to redraw, not the actual time it takes the server to process it [right?]

Comment: Specifically, which Javascript and CSS options are you referring to? 
As for dividing the manager into separate contexts, that's already been set up.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Modx Revo are you using? There have been alot of recent performance improvements in past few releases.

[Related Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702409/modx-revolution-slow-backend)

Comment: Added it in the question. (2.2.2-pl)